# How to extract the current user_id of the user logged in that session?

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables, userid

**Login.php**
What I have been trying to do is extract the session id of the user who is logged in and call it on another page in order to store user_id in the comments table. However, when I tried to do that, it outputs only 0, rather than the user's ID, in the next page.

```
<?php
session_start();
require "../layouts/header.php";//including header
require '../database/db.php';//db connection

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
        {
            $msg = '<label style="color:red;"> Missing fields!</label>';
        }
        else
        {
            //checking if the provided credential match with the database
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users where username=:username";
            $statement = $db->prepare($query);
            //criteria for successful login
            $condition = [
                'username'=>$_POST['username']

            ];
            $statement->execute($condition);

            $count = $statement->rowCount();
            if($count > 0)
            {                   
                $users=$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $pwd = $_POST['password'];
                    //verification of password
                    if (password_verify($pwd, $users->password))
                    {
                        $type = $_POST['type'];
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
                        foreach( $users as $view):
                        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $view['user_id'];

                        if($type==$view['type'] && $type == 1)
                        {
                            header("location:../admin/index.php"); 
                        }
                        if($type==$view['type'] && $type == 0)
                        {
                            header("location:../client-side/index.php?user_id=<?= $view->user_id; ?>");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "Invalid!";
                        }    
                        endforeach; 
                    }
                    else{
                        echo '<label style="color:red;"> Invaid Entry!</label>';
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                $msg = '<label style="color:red;"> Invaid Entry!</label>';
            }
        }
    }
```

?>
**Login Form**

```
<main class="home" style="margin-bottom: 30px; margin-top:30px;">
    <h2 style="text-align: center">Login</h2>
    <hr>

    <form action="login.php" method="POST">

        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username"><br>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"><br>
        <label><strong>Please select one:</strong></label> 
        <label>Admin</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" id="Admin" value="1" style="margin-top: 33px; height:20px;width:20px;"><br>
        <label>Client</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" id="Client" value="0" style="margin-top: 33px; height:20px;width:20px;"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
    </form>

    <div style="height: 200px;"></div>

    <br>
</main>

    <?php            
    require "../layouts/footer.php"; 
    ?>
```

**index.php** the index page only outputs 0 rather than the user_id

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"]))
    {
        echo '<h1> Welcome - '.$_SESSION["user_id"].'</h1>';

    }
?>
```

Comment: I assume you want to show `john.doe` instead of `0` (which, based on your code, is simply the row ID in the database) ?. If that's the case, why don't you use the `$_SESSION['username']` variable ?

Comment: did you put `session_start()` at the top of your index.php (or in a file which is `require`d or `include`d by index.php earlier in the script)? That's needed before you can read anything from the session.

Comment: Thank you @noah but I want to check if the id is getting passed or not . Yes a session start is available. It does print the username but my problem is the logged in id is not getting passed to the user_id

Comment: Ok so let's trace it back. `foreach( $users as $view):
                        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $view['user_id'];` looks wrong. `$users` should already be an array containing one row from the table. You don't need to loop it (that would loop through the individual properties of the object, which isn't needed). Try just `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $users["user_id"];` instead. Similarly, other references to `$views` later on should also be replaced with `$users`, I believe.

Comment: P.S. I'm surprised that `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $view['user_id'];` isn't generating a warning about an undefined index or similar? Have you suppressed warnings in your PHP setup, or something? Or did you forget to check your log files perhaps?

Comment: Or might need to be `$users->user_id` since it's an object

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code on my own machine and it seems as though your issue is the foreach loop you have. I don't think you need to run the foreach as you have already fetched a single object with PDO::FETCH_OBJ.

Also, you are trying to access the user_id property from your $view class as an array.

I think a simple modification to your code should suffice. Note that you will be getting the username because you are assigning it to the session directly from the $_POST variable, before the foreach loop.

```
<?php
session_start();
require "../layouts/header.php";//including header
require '../database/db.php';//db connection

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
        {
            $msg = '<label style="color:red;"> Missing fields!</label>';
        }
        else
        {
            //checking if the provided credential match with the database
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users where username=:username";
            $statement = $db->prepare($query);
            //criteria for successful login
            $condition = [
                'username'=>$_POST['username']

            ];
            $statement->execute($condition);

            $count = $statement->rowCount();
            if($count > 0)
            {                   
                $users=$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $pwd = $_POST['password'];
                    //verification of password
                    if (password_verify($pwd, $users->password))
                    {
                        $type = $_POST['type'];
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

                        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->user_id;

                        if($type==$user->type && $type == 1)
                        {
                            header("location:../admin/index.php"); 
                        }
                        if($type==$user->type && $type == 0)
                        {
                            header("location:../client-side/index.php?user_id=<?= $user->user_id; ?>");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "Invalid!";
                        }    
                    }
                    else{
                        echo '<label style="color:red;"> Invaid Entry!</label>';
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                $msg = '<label style="color:red;"> Invaid Entry!</label>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: $view is now undefined in this example